# How to check AppBarLayout.Behavior dragCallback was set?

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

I am trying to unit test that the behavior with a custom DragCallback was set on my AppBarLayout.
There is a set method for setting the dragCallback but not a getter method.

```
AppBarLayout.Behavior behavior = new AppBarLayout.Behavior();
behavior.setDragCallback(new AppBarLayoutCustomCallback());
```

It there any way to access the dragCallback of appbarlayout.behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up decomposing the creation of the behavior and for the unit test and verify that setDragCallBack was called with my custom behavior callback

```
protected AppBarLayout.Behavior createBehaviorWithCallBack(AppBarLayout.Behavior behavior) {
    behavior.setDragCallback(new MyCustomCallback());
    return behavior;
}
```

and for the unit test

```
assertNotNull(behavior);
verify(behavior).setDragCallback(any(MyCustomCallback.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to get the `DragCallback` field form Behavior of the AppBarLayout. That field is private and getter is not available probably not to distort the behavior.

```
  private AppBarLayout.Behavior.DragCallback getDragCallback(AppBarLayout appBarLayout){
        CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) appBarLayout.getLayoutParams();
        CoordinatorLayout.Behavior behavior = layoutParams.getBehavior();
        if(behavior != null){
            try {
                Field mDragCallbackField = behavior.getClass().getDeclaredField("mDragCallback");
                mDragCallbackField.setAccessible(true);
                AppBarLayout.Behavior.DragCallback dragCallback = (AppBarLayout.Behavior.DragCallback) mDragCallbackField.get(behavior);
                return dragCallback;
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Then just `assertNotNull(getDragCallback(mAppBarLayout))`;